# How can I create a GWT button with both image and text?

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to create a GWT button that includes both an image and text like this:

[image: Drawing of desired button]

I can create and set the button image like this:

```
PushButton button = new PushButton();
button.getUpFace().setImage(new Image(icon));
```

but if I do this the image disappears:

```
button.setText("ABC");
```

How can I keep both?  I would prefer not to use the setHtml method because that would create a new HTTP request

EDIT: The problem with calling setHTML() is that it causes the browser to send another HTTP request to the server.  This means that when I change the icon the button is blank for a second or two while the browser waits for a response from the server - obviously this not ideal.   I'm looking for a way to use the image that is in memory in the form of a ImageResource object.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to achieve this.

Please have a look at below post asked in the same context:

- [HTML/CSS - Adding an Icon to a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490216/html-css-adding-an-icon-to-a-button)
- [Adding icons to an button in gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743492/adding-icons-to-an-button-in-gwt)
- [GWT Custom Button with Icon above Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431020/gwt-custom-button-with-icon-above-text)

Sample code:

```
Button button = new Button();

// get image form CSS resource
String url = new Image(Resources.INSTANCE.cut()).getUrl();
// get image from url
String url = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/tango-icon-library/48/edit-cut-64.png";
// get image from the project war/images folder
String url = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "images/cut.png";

String html = "<div><center><img src = '" + url
        + "'></img></center><label>Cut</label></br></div>";

button.setHTML(html);
```

**Note:** you can move it to CSS as well and append in HTML.

___________-

**EDIT**

**You can achieve it using `PushButton` as well using `setInnerHTML()`method that will benefit from `ImageResource` as well.**

```
final PushButton pushButton = new PushButton(new Image(Resources.INSTANCE.old_cut_icon()));
pushButton.getElement().setInnerHTML("<div><center>"+pushButton.getElement().getInnerHTML()+"</center><label><center>Cut</center></label></div>");
```

now simply call `setImage()` whenever needed to change the icon only.

```
pushButton.getUpFace().setImage(new Image(Resources.INSTANCE.new_cut_icon()));
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that produces the correct layout but means the button will be blank for a second or two when the image is changed (see my edit above)

Comment: @Mark share your code. What are you doing actually?

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uFGkU6528E&feature=youtu.be  Notice that the 'Draw' button icon is blank for a short while whenever it is changed

Comment: Right now my code is simply:   button.getUpFace().setHTML(
    "<img width='32' height='32' src='images/" + icon + ".png'/><br/>" + label);

Comment: @Mark OK I got it now that what you want to say.

Comment: @Mark create multiple buttons and only one shown at a time and others are hidden in the background.

Comment: @Mark I have updated my post that will use the images from memory as ImageResource using `PushButton`.

Comment: @@Braj Strangely for me that produces text above the image: http://imgur.com/rNfSu3Z

Comment: Braj - I have decided to follow your suggestion and create multiple buttons each with a different icon, then display the only appropriate button.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mark I think the actual issue flickering and delay issue are resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Set a text on your button. Also set a CSS style:

```
.myButton {
    background-image:url('/images/icon/cut.png');
    background-position:center top;
    padding: 28px 2px 2px;
}
```

Adjust padding depending on the size of your image.

An alternative approach is to create a widget that combines a button with a label, and either (1) put them in a LayoutPanel, specifying the position that you want, or (2) use CSS to move the label on top of the button (better).

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it replaces the background image used by GWT to give a subtle gradient effect on the button

Comment: I updated the response (you did not mention the gradient). If your text is not dynamic, it may be easier to create an image that combines both an icon and a text in Photoshop.