# How can I merge 2 elements in HTML-CSS-JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, tags

I want to merge 2 elements(buttons, to be precise) into 1 in HTML & CSS, with if needed, Javascript.
Here's the HTML-CSS code:

```css
#downloadButtonDiv {
  display: flexbox;
  justify-content: left;
}

#downloadButton {
  background-color: #00B0F0;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: #00B0F0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-right: 0cm;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 275px;
}

#downloadButtonIcon {
  background-color: #23a5d4;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: #23a5d4;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 0cm;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="downloadButtonDiv">
  <button type="button" id="downloadButton">Download</button>
  <button type="button" id="downloadButtonIcon"><img src="#" width=50/></button>
</div>
```

This produces 2 buttons, side-by-side, but not merged together. Even nesting buttons inside another doesn't help. What should I do?

Here's how I want my button to look like(exclude the gray background, of course.):

[image: The Image]

> The Image was made in `Figma`, if anybody was wondering.

Comment: Check out `position: absolute;` and see if it helps: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Why do you have two buttons? Do you simply want an icon on your first button? see: [HTML/CSS - Adding an Icon to a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490216/html-css-adding-an-icon-to-a-button)

Comment: the color is different, is that purposeful?

Comment: @pilchard, Sir, I have two buttons as I want to merge them and make them look as if there is just one button but with two sections.

Comment: @depperm,  Yeah I made the colors different purposefully because as I have the intent of merging them, there background should look different so they can be distinguished from one another.

Comment: I don't usually post w3schools links but [How TO - Button Group](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_group.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```css
.downloadButton {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  place-items: center;

  background-color: #00B0F0;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: #00B0F0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-right: 0cm;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 275px;
}
```

```html
  <button type="button" class="downloadButton"><img src="https://picsum.photos/32/32" width=50/><span>Download</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain a bit more about what you actually want to do. From the looks of it, I'd first think that you just want to have 1 Button with an icon and text.

In this case you could just `<button id="downloadButton">Download <span id="downloadButtonIcon"></span></button>` and style the span accordingly to show the icon. If this is not your intent, please clarify as stated above!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use 2 buttons to display an icon/image on the background of a button. Simply use `position: relative;` for the button and `position: absolute;` for the image. Then you can adjust the location of the image using `top-left-right-bottom` attributes. The code below expands the image so that it covers the button completely.

```
<style>

#downloadButton {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #00B0F0;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #00B0F0;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-right: 0cm;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 75px;
    width: 275px;
}

#downloadButton img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

</style>

<button id="downloadButton">
    Download
    <img src="#" alt="">
</button>
```